# Membership checking against current Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership

I have a web application (MVC) that uses Membership for auth/auth where the user can have more than one Role and multiples countries with diferent roles.

Let say, user1 is Admin and Editor in USA and only Editor in Mexico. When the users logs in to the system he is prompted to select both (country and role).

AdminController has [Authorize(Rol = "Admin")] attribute.

In this case if the user is logged in USA as Editor an action in AdminContoller has to be forbbiden.

Which is the "better" approach to check the Role which the user is currently logged on?

Comment: Perhaps you could override the Authorize attribute.  [Authorize(Rol = "Admin/Mexico")] become Admin & Mexico.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Authorize attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // Code here checks that user is Admin for currently selected Country
    }
}
```

and then use your attribute as so:

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute (Roles="Admin")]
```

[This article](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/24/writing-your-own-custom-aspnet-mvc-authorize-attributes) covers the subject in more detail.